# XMLHttpRequest POST method to PHP server receives no POST params but GET fine

Tags: php, javascript, post, xmlhttprequest

I am a newbie attempting to use XMLHttpRequest. I have studied numerous examples scattered across the Internet. I have no problems using the GET method, but when I tried switching to POST it fails to transfer the parameters. :(

Here is my stripped down example which replicates the problem:

Javascript:

```
function GetPostTest(url)
{
  var req       = null;
  var postParms = 'p1=x&p2=y';
  var getParms  = '';
  getParms = 'g1=a&g2=b';
  if ( getParms )  url += '?'+getParms;
  req = new XMLHttpRequest
  if ( req )
  {
    req.open( 'POST', url, true );
    req.setRequestHeader( "Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" );
    req.setRequestHeader( "Content-length", postParms.length );
    req.setRequestHeader( "Connection", "close" );
    req.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
      if ( req.readyState == 4 && req.status == 200 )
      {
        alert( 'Got Stuff Back: ' + req.responseText );
      }
    }
    req.send( postParms );
  }
}
```

Server:

```
<?php
foreach ( $_POST as $key=>$value )      echo htmlspecialchars(' _POST['.$key.']=['.$value.']');
foreach ( $_GET as $key=>$value )       echo htmlspecialchars(' _GET['.$key.']=['.$value.']');
foreach ( $_REQUEST as $key=>$value )   echo htmlspecialchars(' _REQUEST['.$key.']=['.$value.']');
exit;
?>
```

In this example, the server just reports back all of the GET and POST parameters it received which are then shown in the alert box.  I have thrown a couple of GET parameters in there also.  The parameters I pass are:

- GET:  g1=a&g2=b
- PUT:  p1=x&p2=y

The alert box shows: "Got Stuff Back: _GET[g1]=[a] _GET[g2]=[b] _REQUEST[g1]=[a] _REQUEST[g2]=[b]".  This tells me that it is sending to the server okay, and coming back okay, just that the POST variables are not coming through.

I turn off the getParms so I only send POST parameters and then I see no variables.  I turn off any combination of the three setRequestHeader()'s or other variations I see in sample code, and it does not change anything.

I am testing with Google Chromium Version 24.0.1312.56 Ubuntu 11.10 (24.0.1312.56-0ubuntu0.11.10.1) and Apache on Xubuntu 2.2.20-1ubuntu1.3 with PHP.

Thanks for your analysis.  What does it take to fix this to push the POST parameters through?

Comment: The javascript works for me. If you open the chrome dev tools (push F12) and then run your javascript does the chrome dev tools report the headers being sent correctly (You can look under Network then XHR and then click on the request and look at the headers)

Comment: Worked for me as well on FF19 and Chrome25. Could be be some other JS on the same page? or maybe remove this line just to test?    req.setRequestHeader( "Connection", "close" );

Comment: Thanks dsas and Scott Yang.  Your comments led me down the path to the answer.

Looking at the Network - XHR on Chromium developer tools, I saw that it was sending a POST, getting back 301 "Redirected Permanently", and then retrying it as a GET.  I found in my Apache configuration that it redirects non-GET requests for a directory that does not end in a slash.  Adding a slash to the end of the url solved the problem.  Since I am a newbie with no reputation, I cannot answer my question for 8 hours, so I can only leave it as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I just copied your code and tried it and it worked just fine.

Comment: Yes the code works.  Thanks.  See the comments above.  The problem was that the URL does not end in a slash, so Apache was returning 301 and causing a retry with GET.  Adding a slash to the end of my url solved the problem.